# Body does not spread to 100% of the page´s height

Tags: html, css, html-tbody

I am trying to make my footer go to the bottom of the page. The problem is that the body is not taking 100% of the page´s height, that is why the footer cannot go to the bottom (at least this is what I think is happening). Has to be a beginner problem, sorry for asking cause for sure it has been asked before.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(
    at top left,

    #403b4a 0%,
    #e7e9bb 100%
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
```

[actual view of the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YUkP.jpg)

Comment: Add height to html and body `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: also give your footer `margin-top: auto`. since your body has `display: flex; flex-direction: column`, it will make it take all the extra space above it as margin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with the structure of my project? Here is where my navBar, content and footer are placed:

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="content">{children}</div>
      <footer>
        <p>Copyright 2022 Simon Criado</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that. I added `justify-content: space-between;` to the body, which will allow the elements to be pushed apart with flex.

```css
html,
body, 
.layout,
#app {
  height:100%;
}

.layout{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div>Navbar</div>
  <div class="content">Your content</div>
  <div>Footer</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```